# How to convert elements of two lists into a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a simple problem that I'm finding problematic and I need some help with it. I want to convert two lists into data points.

example:
Data:
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [6,7,8,9,10]

Wanted output:
C = [[1,6], [2,7], [3,8], [4,9], [5,10]]

It's like a bijective function in mathematics, but I have no idea how to implement it in code. It doesn't have to be lists. Vectors, Matrices, Arrays. Really anything will do. I have thousands of observations and I want a quick way to group them in the above fashion so I can analyze them. Right now, I'm doing a bunch of workarounds by exporting it from different software. I've tried using For loops and even indexing, but I just can't seem to get it right. New to writing code! Please help!

P.S. I'm using Python.

Comment: You should know Pythons built-in functions. Have a look at [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
import itertools
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [6,7,8,9,10]

list(itertools.izip(A,B))
```

Result:

```
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

or

with list comprehension like this :

```
[list(k) for k in itertools.izip(A,B)]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

Comment: Python 3 has been out since 2008. You should be using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) no longer has `izip()`.  Even in python2 plain old zip would have been a better choice here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea there were so many ways to do this! This is extremely helpful! Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [6,7,8,9,10]
C = list(map(lambda x, y:[x,y], A, B))
print (C)
```

This would give the following output

```
[[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: Wow! This actually worked so quick! Thanks so much, friend!